# How to view first image in list per user as its highlight Profile

Tags: php, mysql

A user can save up to five images in a table. I want to view **single image with** `uid` on the **Homepage**.
I knew how to view all images from the table. But, How can I retrieve multiple users with a single image on the home page arrange them in upload_time order?

So that new profiles are view on the Home page.
[My table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1j0h.png) 
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$query2="SELECT * FROM member_images";
$result2=mysqli_query($db,$query2);
?>
     <div class="r_members_inner">
                      <?php  $i=1;
                            while($rows=mysqli_fetch_object($result2))
                            { 
                        ?>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="<?php echo "member_images/".$rows->file_name; ?>" height="200px" alt="">
                        <h4><?php echo $rows->uid;  ?></h4>
                        <h5>22 years old</h5>
                    </div>
                    <?php $i++; }?>
                </div>
```

> Problem is that it show all images of all users. I want per user one image. How can I achive it.

Comment: Post code. Which I try.

Comment: Thank you everyone for down vote it help me to find answer my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looping on all results of your query, so of course you will get all images.  Your query is to generic.

Now I assume your table is something like this:
- id, int, auto-increment, primary key
- uid, varchar, foreing key from a user table, not null
- file_name, varchar, not-null
- upload_time, datetime, not-null

Modify it to get only the 1 image you want:

```
SELECT file_name
FROM member_images
WHERE uid = <SOME UID>
ORDER BY upload_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

DESC will order the results by latest first.  So LIMIT 1 will get only the first image, which is the latest.

Now if you want to get the latest image for every user in one go, use:

```
SELECT *
FROM member_images AS m
INNER JOIN (SELECT uid, max(upload_time) as latest
            FROM member_images
            GROUP BY uid) AS r
            ON m.upload_time = r.latest and m.uid = r.uid
ORDER BY upload_time DESC
```

BTW I did not know how to do this either, so I searched the web, and I found
many pages on StackOverflow on how to do it.  Hence the downvotes.  Folks here
expect you to do your own research.

Nic